# Problems in rank of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a $5{\times}7$ matrix of rank $5$ and $B$ is a $7{\times}5$ matrix of rank $5$ and $AB= I$, then find rank of $BA$ and nullity of $BA$.

Using $\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}\rank(AB)\le\min(\rank A,\rank B)$ I have $\rank (AB)\le 5$ but since $AB =I$ we have $\rank AB$ is 5

Similarly $\rank(BA)\le 5$ but I am unable to find the particular value of $\rank(BA)$...
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Interpret in terms of the associated linear maps: if $K$ is the base field, $A$ is the matrix of a linear map $f:K^7\longrightarrow K^5$, $B$ the matrix of $g:K^5\longrightarrow K^7$, and $AB=I_5$ means $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_{K^5}$.

This implies  $g$ is injective, and $f$ is surjective. So $\ker(g\circ f)=\ker f$ and $\operatorname{Im}(g\circ f)=\operatorname{Im}g$.

Can you conclude with these elements?

Comment: Then we have to find dimensions of ker f...

Comment: Is here rank(AB)= rank(BA)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. It is also the rank of $B$ and the rank of $A$.

Comment: One question pls....can you pls tell me when rank ( AB)= rank(BA) is happened! In general I had seen rank ( AB) not equal to rank (BA). And what is the special case here..that the equality occurs.

Comment: First, in general,if $AB$ is defined, $BA$ is not. There are condition on the dimensions of the matrices for both products to be defined. In addition, it happens here that both products have the same rank because $AB=I_5$, which implies it corresponds to the composition off an injection with a surjection. I don't know if there is a more general answer or a necessary and sufficient condition.